# Use resteasy with user and password

Tags: java, resteasy, wowza

I am trying to convert this line to resteasy stuff.

```
curl -X GET --digest -u myuser:mypassword --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/live/instances
```

this is how I am trying to connect to that endpoint

```
clientREST = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        clientREST.register(new BasicAuthentication(userWowza, passWowza));
        String targetStr = "http://" + host + ":" + portEndpoint + endPoint + red5App + "/instances";
        System.out.println(targetStr);
        ResteasyWebTarget target = clientREST
                .target(targetStr);
        Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity("", "application/json"));

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
        }
```

But I get HTTP error code : 401.  So it is like user and password is no working.  Am I sending the headers correctly?

### Update

So I couldnt find any example of resteasy with digest auth, so I found that wowza seems to suppport basic and digest at the same time

Comment: It is always good to use tcpMon or similar tool to capture actual traffic. You  'll be able to see what exactly your client sends. If Authorization header is there and correct, then problem is not in your code

Comment: what about --digest, isnt it using md5 or something like that

Comment: Yes that seems as problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `curl` uses `--digest` not BASIC authentication. So it looks like Server does not accept BASIC Authorization schema.

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps it should. Try to google about it. I did not use digest with reasteasy.

Comment: I googled it before even posting, but I decided to change Wowza authentication from digest to basic.

Comment: It is not up to you to change it. It is in Server. If Server is also yours, then change its settings to accept BASIC authentication. Otherwise there is no other options.

Comment: The server is mine that is why I said I was going to change it to basic, so it is up to me.

Comment: OK sounds great! Usually, I do not have such luxury :-)